# PHP Google Adwords Api v201406: get total clicks, total impressions by campaignId

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am using php adwords api v201406. 
I have 2 questions.

1. How can I get these fields total clicks, total impressions by campaignId. 
   Now I'm using ReportDefinitionService, and get save a file, after I read and parse it, and after that get the data. Is there a way to get the data without saving the file.
2. How can I get  'Headline', 'Description1', 'Description2' by campaignId.
   Now I'm usng 2 requests to get this data (via AdGroupService I am getting all AdGropIds,  and after it via AdGroupAdService I get all data what I need)

Thanks...

Comment: Google Adwords Api developers have already answered to this question. Thanks very much to them
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/community/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Adwords Api developers have already answered to this question. Thanks very much to them developers.google.com/adwords/api/community

Comment: And what's their answer?